# Is there a way to round factors throughout a dataframe using R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a mix of characters and numbers in each column that are ultimately considered character columns like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  Group = c('Type', 'State', 'Roads'),
  Value1 = c('A', 'Florida', 107.188887)
)
```

I want to round the number data points to the tenth digit, but this doesn't seem possible given they are intermingled with other data types. Is there a way to do this rounding using R? The result would look like this:

```
df_desired <- data.frame(
  Group = c('Type', 'State', 'Roads'),
  Value1 = c('A', 'Florida', 107.2)
)
```

I'd prefer to avoid pivoting the df if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the elements that are only numeric and do the `round`ing in `base R` itself

```
i1 <- grep("^[0-9.]+$", df1$Value1)
df1$Value1[i1] <- round(as.numeric(df1$Value1[i1]), 1)
```

-output

```
> df1
  Group  Value1
1  Type       A
2 State Florida
3 Roads   107.2
```

---

If it is an entire dataset, use `lapply`

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) {
     i1 <- grep("^[0-9.]+$", x)
     x[i1] <- round(as.numeric(x[i1]), 1)
    x
})
```

-output

```
> df1
  Group  Value1
1  Type       A
2 State Florida
3 Roads   107.2
```

Comment: This is very good. What's the best way to apply it across an entire dataframe? Unfortunately, my data is much longer than a single column.

Comment: @NatashaR. updated the post

Answer (score 1):

First `str_detect`the numerical value, then `str_extract` it, convert it to numeric with `as.numeric`, and finally `round` it:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(Value1 = ifelse(str_detect(Value1, "^[\\d.]+$"),
                           round(as.numeric(str_extract(Value1, "^[\\d.]+$")),1),
                           Value1))
  Group  Value1
1  Type       A
2 State Florida
3 Roads   107.2
```

**EDIT**:

If this type of edit needs to be done in several columns, you can `mutate(across`:

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("V"),
                ~ifelse(str_detect(., "^[\\d.]+$"),
                         round(as.numeric(str_extract(., "^[\\d.]+$")),1),
                         .)))

df1 <- data.frame(
  Group = c('Type', 'State', 'Roads'),
  Value1 = c('A', 'Florida', 107.188887),
  Value2 = c('B', 'California', 234.1229997)
)
```

This much more concise method works too (Warnings can be ignored):

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("V"),
                ~ifelse(str_detect(., "^[\\d.]+$"),
                         round(as.numeric(.),1),
                         .)))
```